# ajax - jsonp - кросс-доменные запросы

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp

Столкнувшись с проблемой:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy 
  disallows reading the remote resource at
  http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/40. This can be 
  fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

Прогуглил и решил использовать jsonp, что бы обойти это. Изменил json на jsonp. К урлу добавил '?callback=?', в итоге ошибка:

```
NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND -
http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/40?
  callback=jQuery1112027875676172209374_1428411637023&_=1428411637024
```

Мой код:

```
function fantasy(){
  start(categor='http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/', 1, 40);
}
function start(categor, ot, te) {
  var start = Math.floor((Math.random() * ot) + te);
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: categor+start+'?callback=?',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'callback',
    success: function (data) {
      if (data.pk == start) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = data.title;
        document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = '<img class="img-responsive" src="img/poetry/'+data.img+'"/>';
        document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = '<h4>Описание:</h4>'+data.content;
        document.getElementById('author').innerHTML = '<span>Автор: </span>'+data.author;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Что я сделал не так?

**Решение:** спасибо всем, в какой-то мере все варианты решают проблему, именно в моем случае, т. к. сервер написан на Django, то помогла библиотека - **django-cors-headers** - https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/
+ изменение в settings.py CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

Comment: А ты пробовал просто вбить в адресной строке этот запрос? Судя по тому что это GET, должен отработать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В браузере ты заходишь на `http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/40`
или на `localhost:8000/snippets/40` - попробуй изменить

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/40
```

на

```
localhost:8000/snippets/40
```

У тебя проблема в политике запрета обращения к чужому адресу ajaxом - тебе либо надо указать access-origin: all на принимающей стороне - либо обращаться к себе на сервер со своего сервера (урл запроса и урл в браузере должны быть одинаковы)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, Поменял на localhost - продвигаюсь дальше и получаю ошибку 
`SyntaxError: missing ; before statement`
 Значит что то еще мне не хватает для получения jsonp

Comment: @AlexeyAl гдето пропустил точку с запятой! Сейчас поищем

Comment: @AlexeyAl почему не просто function fantasy(){
  start('http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/', 1, 40);
}

Comment: привычка из Python указывать значение переменной по дефолту) просто вроде как нет разницы.

Comment: видимо нужно больше кода твоего - потому что в текущем ошибки не нашел

Comment: Спасибо за старания - но это вроде как весь код =) Тут еще такое заметил - если я сайт сотру, а сохраню этот массив в файл example.json например и подключу путь к нему а так же махну jsonp на json, всё отлично и красиво. Остаётся одно, запрос callback - с ним проблемы.

Comment: покажи мне console.log(data)

Comment: Так там же ошибка ajax запрос не удался тобиш success не будет и получается и посмотреть не знаю как(

Comment: возможно нашел решение но пока не обдумал его - что то вроде api не поддерживает jsonp http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24228002/syntaxerror-missing-before-statement-jsonp

Comment: переделать под просто json не вариант?

Comment: Я первоначально  json принимаю - но идет ошибка кросдоменности , поэтому пытаюсь заменить это на jsonp

Comment: важный вопрос - откуда ты делаешь запрос и куда? Ошибка кроссдоменности - банальная и легко лечится, при наличие доступа к обеим сторонам?

Comment: сервер на django возвращает страницу с содержимым в виде json(localhost:8000) - аякс подхватывает и выводит просто  в хтмл файл, который я запускаю (localhost:63342)

Comment: web.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')  нужна такая штука в конфиге веб сервера - чтобы принимать запросы отовсюду и отвечать, на продакшне - лучше ограничить белым листом

Answer (score 0):

Если страница и сервер на одном домене, то можно не делать кроссдоменный запрос, а ходить аяксом по относительным урлам безо всякого jsonp. Т.е. вместо урла

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/

Указать просто:

> /snippets/

Если же на разных - то на стороне сервера в заголовках ответа надо добавить:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yourdomain.ru // Можно написать all, но тогда сервер не сможет выставлять куки
```

На стороне jQuery соответственно:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    ...
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    }
    ...
});
```

Тогда можно обойтись без jsonp